# ant to detect FreeBSD

Tags: java, ant, freebsd

Is there a way to detect FreeBSD with ant. I used `os.name` it shows it as Linux. I want to differentiate between FreeBSD and Linux.

Comment: That's weird, I would really expect the returned string to be *FreeBSD* (and I see lots of references of that on the internet).

Comment: yes, Thats what I was expecting. I don't know what would make ant report it as linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would using `uname -a` be good....you can do it this way....

```
uname -a | grep FreeBSD
```

Comment: Ok. I was expecting to have something inside ant system properties, but I can use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your JDK is a Linux version running under emulation, instead of a FreeBSD-native one, that could explain the OS being reported as Linux.

Comment: Yes, I found that out later and once I installed diablo (freebsd) java ant detects the OS as freeBSD